# Why is my for loop not updating my variable?

Tags: javascript, rest

Complete newbie question here. I am trying to loop through some data and ONLY run a function if I my retrieved data doesn't match items in the array. I set a boolean variable to false and was thinking to change the value of it to 'true' if a match was found. If I log my variable directly after assigning it a 'true' value, it works as expected. If I log it outside my for loop, it is back to false. Any tips for a beginner? Thanks!

```
    var matchFound = false; 
    currentUserRequest.done(function (userData) {       
        for(var i = 0;i < arr.length;i++){
            var item = arr[i];
            console.log("request = " + request);
            console.log("item.RequestName = " + item.RequestName);
            console.log("current user = " + userData.d.Title);
            console.log("item.Author[Title] = " + item.Author["Title"]);                
            if(request == item.RequestName && userData.d.Title == item.Author["Title"]){
                matchFound = true;
                //this is returning true as expected
                console.log(matchFound);
            }

        } 
    });
    //this is returning 'false', though I changed it to true above
    console.log(matchFound);
```

Comment: It is. It's just doing it **after** the `console.log` at the bottom of the code above, because the `done` callback is called later, asynchronously.

Comment: thats because you're running async, your console log at the end will be executed too early

Comment: Thanks for the replies. It was helpful in finding a starting point for digging.